# Strap Mount Bracket, what is it called?

Tags: brackets

I am looking for a strap mount bracket.  I have seen them on products but I need to buy one for a home project and can't find one for sale, probably because I don't know what it is called.

The bracket is made from an 1/8 inch round stock, it is about 2 inches (or shorter) and raised slightly.  It mounts to a flat surface like wood or metal.  A strap goes through and swings back around.  Generally used when applying 5 or 10 pounds holding power, where the strap will be loosed and re-tightened occasionally.

[image]

Comment: So, it screws to wood or metal and then the straps hold another object to the bracket?  Like a [fire extinguisher bracket](http://i21.geccdn.net/site/images/n-picgroup/FCO_24.jpg) ?

Comment: Kind of, it attaches to wood or metal, the strap goes through and then you tighten the strap. When the size of the load is variable it allows for easy adjustment.  I wish I could remember where I have seen it used so I could find a picture of it in use.

Comment: You talking about a nylon strap?  What have you seen them holding in the past?

Comment: Yes a nylon strap, I just remember the bracket, I have a perfect picture of it in my mind, but can't remember what it was on.  I have been searching google without finding it.

Comment: How about [this](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Scotch-1-5-in-x-6-in-Bracket-with-30-in-Black-Garage-Organizer-Bundling-Strap-RF3780/204465411) or [this](http://www.flowwall.com/Flow-Wall-Storage-Systems-Balistic-Nylon-Strap-Hook-3pk) ?

Comment: Last idea...  You question originally made me think of brackets that are used to connect signs to round poles like [these](http://www.band-strap.com/universal-channel-clamps.html), but it sounds like you want something similar where the "sign" would be your wall, and the "pole" would be your load.

Comment: It is very much like the [strap hook](http://www.flowwall.com/Flow-Wall-Storage-Systems-Balistic-Nylon-Strap-Hook-3pk) but is much simpler.  You would be able to buy several for one dollar.

Comment: How much do you _need_ to hold with it?  What's your application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is a "strap loop". On at least one site it seems to be called a footman loop.

https://www.google.com/search?q=strap+loop

[image]